# Taking pointer from text box after enter value, i need to call javascript

Tags: javascript

Enter value to a text field,  can select the text field using mouse only. after enter the value i click submit button. Before click submit button , while taking pointer from text box after enter value . i need to call javascript. For this which event i use?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly. This event **"blur**"

`input.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
   var value = e.target.value;
});`